# Google Bigquery PHP API Allowed memory size exhausted in Google/Http/REST.php

Tags: google-bigquery

Google Bigquery's PHP API emits a fatal error when querying the results of a job.  The actual error is:

> **Fatal error**:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in
>   **/.../google-api-php-client-1.1.6/src/Google/Http/REST.php** on
>   line **119**

Any ideas what could be causing this error?

Comment: Hi @rmg! You can move your answer from the comments section to the answers one, and get stackoverflow points for it - or I can do it, so the questions counts as "answered" too. I'm glad you could solve this, and thanks for sharing the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

This was being caused by the getQueryResults call returning too many rows. This can be fixed by setting maxResults in the optional args to a limiting value, ie:

```
response = gbq_service->jobs->getQueryResults($project_id, $jobId, array('timeoutMs' => 100000, 'maxResults'=>1000));
```